# Robotframework: SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Error: NS_BINDING_ABORTED

Tags: robotframework

I am getting the below error when trying to execute the robotframework test scripts.

### Parent suite setup failed:
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Error: NS_BINDING_ABORTED
Stacktrace:
#checkLoadingState@chrome://remote/content/shared/Navigate.jsm:209:28
onStateChange@chrome://remote/content/shared/Navigate.jsm:254:28

Tests.Suites.Layer2.Dhl.Dhl Session                                   | FAIL |
Suite setup failed:
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Error: NS_BINDING_ABORTED
Stacktrace:
#checkLoadingState@chrome://remote/content/shared/Navigate.jsm:209:28
onStateChange@chrome://remote/content/shared/Navigate.jsm:254:28

Below are the list of files installed:

I installed python 3.10.5

C:\aoswebtest>pip list
Package                        Version

---

async-generator                1.10
attrs                          21.4.0
bcrypt                         3.2.2
certifi                        2022.5.18.1
cffi                           1.15.0
cryptography                   36.0.1
et-xmlfile                     1.1.0
h11                            0.13.0
idna                           3.3
openpyxl                       3.0.9
outcome                        1.1.0
paramiko                       2.11.0
pip                            22.0.4
pycparser                      2.21
pydevd                         2.7.0
PyNaCl                         1.5.0
pyOpenSSL                      22.0.0
PyYAML                         6.0
robotframework                 4.1.3
robotframework-pythonlibcore   3.0.0
robotframework-seleniumlibrary 6.0.0
robotframework-sshlibrary      3.8.0
scapy                          2.4.5
scp                            0.14.4
selenium                       4.1.0
setuptools                     58.1.0
six                            1.16.0
sniffio                        1.2.0
sortedcontainers               2.4.0
trio                           0.20.0
trio-websocket                 0.9.2
urllib3                        1.26.9
webcolors                      1.11.1
wsproto                        1.1.0
xlrd                           2.0.1

Can you anyone help my with this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error. I used my pc and run selenium with firefox then it works fine. But when I copy code and run other pc, it shows error NS_BINDING_ABORTED.
I fix it by: downgrade firefox version(from 103.x.x -> 92.x.x)